# Find (numbers) difference between two fields (numbers are comma separeted) using mysql (or maybe PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

First column consists of all numbers that is need for the field, and the second one is some of numbers that are in the first column.

So, i should find the numbers that does not consist second column but exist in the first column.

For example, in the first row, i should return number:157, as it exists the first row, but not in the second one.

Comment: And you want to do this in MySQL because...?

Comment: what is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: @Strawberry, tried the solution with PHP, using methods like `array_diff_key` and other custom methods for multidimensional array. They do not help because, two array consists of several arrays (multidimensional arrays). If you have any idea, in PHP, welcome)

Comment: @Dimgold varchar of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's wrong with the following:

```
<?php
$my_array = array
            (
              'first' => array
                         (
                           array(31,33,41,55,63,71,124,146,157,212),
                           array(55,57,70,71,72,73,74,76,124,158)
                         ),
              'second' => array
                         (
                           array(63,71,41,124,146,33,55,31,212),
                           array(71,57,70,124,158,55,76,72)
                         )
            );


for($i=0;$i<count($my_array['first']);$i++){
print_r(array_diff($my_array['first'][$i],array_intersect($my_array['first'][$i],$my_array['second'][$i])));
}

?>
```

Outputs; Array ( [8] => 157 ) Array ( [5] => 73 [6] => 74 )

It's worth pointing out that I'm no PHP coder, so I'm sure there's room for considerable improvement... but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is only for one row. I have 1000 rows!

Comment: @AibolOrazbekov The manual provides a brief explanation for parsing multidimensional arrays using this function. The point is, this kind of task is what PHP is really good at, and MySQL really isn't..